# Editing Button text in JavaFX with many threads

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I use Java FX nad Java 7.0.51.

I have two apps: Server and Client. In the server app I have a additional thread which checks if the client send sth to the server. If yes, I must change Button text using `button.setText('STH');` Unfortunately, I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX is like most other GUI toolkits single threaded, thus every change to the GUI must be done on the GUI Thread otherwise the `IllegalStateException` is thrown.

You can schedule GUI updates outside the GUI Thread with [`Platform.runLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).